# Advice on how to set up storyboard so elements do not overlap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uiimage

I am trying to figure this out despite reading Apple docs such as the [guide for Windows and Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW1).

My issue is best illustrated by this screen capture:

[image]

As you can see the blog post has a picture with variable height (but fixed width = 320px), which may or may not overlap with the view element below it, which is a label.

Similar to what one would do with CSS, I would need the UIImageView to be "display:block", as well as the label.

So if the image occupies more or less vertical space, the element below would adjust its position accordingly. Is this only done programatically?

I've tried to do this hierarchically by placing each in their separate view to no avail.
"Clip subviews" is unticked.

Any advice on the general procedure to get this done, or links to relevant material is greatly appreciated.

---

Controller code (postTextLabel and postPicture are connected IBOutlets)

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

- (void)configureView;

@end

@implementation DetailViewController;

@synthesize scroller;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureView];

        CGRect label_frame = CGRectMake(postTextLabel.frame.origin.x,
                                        postPicture.frame.origin.y + postPicture.frame.size.height,
                                        postTextLabel.frame.size.width,
                                        postTextLabel.frame.size.height);

        postTextLabel.frame = label_frame;

}

- (void)configureView
{
    if (self.detailItem) {
        NSDictionary *post           = self.detailItem;
        NSString     *postText       = [post objectForKey:@"post_text"];
        NSString     *postAuthorName = [post objectForKey:@"post_author_name"];

        postTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        postTextLabel.text       = postText;
        postAuthorNameLabel.text = postAuthorName;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSString *pictureUrl = [post objectForKey:@"post_picture"];
            NSData   *data       = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pictureUrl]];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                postPicture.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            });
        });
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you're aiming for is just to have the label snap to the bottom of the image, programmatic is your best approach - I don't think there's a way to do it in Interface Builder. If you set up the image and label as IBOutlets named `image` and `label` respectively, code like the following should give you what you're aiming for:

```
CGRect label_frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x, image.frame.origin.y + image.frame.size.height, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);
label.frame = label_frame;
```

Call this whenever the image is changed and the text should be positioned below it, top edge of the label aligned with the bottom of the image. Remember you may need to alter the scroll view's `contentSize` to match if the image/text becomes larger.

Comment: your code makes total sense to me - when I add it to my DetailViewController.m I get no errors, but it doesn't change the label position. I added the entire controller in OP in case you're interested.

Comment: Updating the image asynchronously may have something to do with that - it's possible the text is being repositioned before the image is updated. Have you tried putting the frame updating code immediately after the call to `postPicture.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];` (inside the async call)?

Comment: good point, now it behaves as expected - apparently it onl works if I choose `aspect fit` in the inspector -- I actually wanted the image to always occupy the same width (320px) but allow height to vary if needed - any ideas?

Comment: Not for sure... if you want it to stretch to width while maintaining the aspect ratio, I'd probably set the image's frame manually - something like `[image sizeToFit];` `float aspect = frame.height/frame.width;` `image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320*aspect);` or something similar. Don't know for sure if it'd work or even if that's what you're after though.